# Embedding Sheet range into Userform

Tags: excel, vba, range, userform

I copied a piece of code from an old forum post with the goal of embedding a sheet range onto a Userform by creating a temporary .bmp picture, displaying it when the form initializes, and deleting it when the closing pop-up.

The code itself runs without bugs about 3/4 times. Although it doesn't seem to follow any particular pattern. it just seems to come and go without reason.

I get the following error message once the code jams:

[image]

Below is a copy of the code that I am running with. How can I find out what is causing the issue?

**Userform initialize code**

```
 Option Explicit
    Dim FileName As String
    
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim img As MSForms.Image
 
Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")  
ws.Range("b2:m22").CopyPicture

    FileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - Len(ThisWorkbook.Name)) & "MyBitmap.bmp"
    SaveClip2Bit FileName
    
    Set img = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "TableImage", True)
    img.Picture = LoadPicture(FileName)
    img.Width = Me.Width
    img.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    
    If FileName <> "" Then Kill FileName
    
    End Sub
```

**Module code**

```
'*****************************************************************
'*
'* MODULE NAME: Paste Picture
'* AUTHOR & DATE: STEPHEN BULLEN, Office Automation Ltd
'* 15 November 1998
'*
'* CONTACT: Stephen@oaltd.co.uk
'* WEB SITE: http://www.oaltd.co.uk
'*
'* DESCRIPTION: Creates a standard Picture object from whatever is on the clipboard.
'* This object can then be assigned to (for example) and Image control
'* on a userform. The PastePicture function takes an optional argument of
'* the picture type - xlBitmap or xlPicture.
'*
'* The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'*
'* The code in this module has been derived from a number of sources
'* discovered on MSDN.
'*
'* To use it, just copy this module into your project, then you can use:
'* Set Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
'* to paste a picture of whatever is on the clipboard into a standard image control.
'*
'* PROCEDURES:
'* PastePicture The entry point for the routine
'* CreatePicture Private function to convert a bitmap or metafile handle to an OLE reference
'* fnOLEError Get the error text for an OLE error code
'***************************************************************************

Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

''' User-Defined Types for API Calls

'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

'''Windows API Function Declarations

'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Close the clipboard
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long

'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long

'The API format types we're interested in
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: PastePicture
'''
''' Purpose: Get a Picture object showing whatever's on the clipboard.
'''
''' Arguments: lXlPicType - The type of picture to create. Can be one of:
''' xlPicture to create a metafile (default)
''' xlBitmap to create a bitmap
'''
''' Date Developer Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98 Stephen Bullen Created
''' 15 Nov 98 Stephen Bullen Updated to create our own copies of the clipboard images
'''



Public Sub SaveClip2Bit(FileName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    'SavePicture PastePicture, Application.GetSaveAsFilename("MyBitmap.bmp", "Bitmap Files (*.bmp), *.bmp")
    SavePicture PastePicture, FileName
End Sub


Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture

'Some pointers
Dim h As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As Long, hPal As Long, lPicType As Long, hCopy As Long

'Convert the type of picture requested from the xl constant to the API constant
lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)

'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)

If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
    'Get access to the clipboard
    h = OpenClipboard(0&)

    If h > 0 Then
        'Get a handle to the image data
        hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)

        'Create our own copy of the image on the clipboard, in the appropriate format.
        If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
            hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
        Else
            hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
        End If

        'Release the clipboard to other programs
        h = CloseClipboard

        'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
        If hPtr <> 0 Then Set PastePicture = CreatePicture(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
    End If
End If

End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: CreatePicture
'''
''' Purpose: Converts a image (and palette) handle into a Picture object.
'''
''' Requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'''
''' Arguments: None
'''
''' Date Developer Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98 Stephen Bullen Created
'''

Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture

' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, IPic As IPicture

'OLE Picture types
Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4

' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
With IID_IDispatch
    .Data1 = &H7BF80980
    .Data2 = &HBF32
    .Data3 = &H101A
    .Data4(0) = &H8B
    .Data4(1) = &HBB
    .Data4(2) = &H0
    .Data4(3) = &HAA
    .Data4(4) = &H0
    .Data4(5) = &H30
    .Data4(6) = &HC
    .Data4(7) = &HAB
End With

' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
With uPicInfo
    .Size = Len(uPicInfo) ' Length of structure.
    .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE) ' Type of Picture
    .hPic = hPic ' Handle to image.
    .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0) ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
End With

' Create the Picture object.
r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

' If an error occured, show the description
If r <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)

' Return the new Picture object.
Set CreatePicture = IPic

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: fnOLEError
'''
''' Purpose: Gets the message text for standard OLE errors
'''
''' Arguments: None
'''
''' Date Developer Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98 Stephen Bullen Created
'''

Private Function fnOLEError(lErrNum As Long) As String

'OLECreatePictureIndirect return values
Const E_ABORT = &H80004004
Const E_ACCESSDENIED = &H80070005
Const E_FAIL = &H80004005
Const E_HANDLE = &H80070006
Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
Const E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
Const E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
Const E_OUTOFMEMORY = &H8007000E
Const E_POINTER = &H80004003
Const E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
Const S_OK = &H0

Select Case lErrNum
Case E_ABORT
    fnOLEError = " Aborted"
Case E_ACCESSDENIED
    fnOLEError = " Access Denied"
Case E_FAIL
    fnOLEError = " General Failure"
Case E_HANDLE
    fnOLEError = " Bad/Missing Handle"
Case E_INVALIDARG
    fnOLEError = " Invalid Argument"
Case E_NOINTERFACE
    fnOLEError = " No Interface"
Case E_NOTIMPL
    fnOLEError = " Not Implemented"
Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
    fnOLEError = " Out of Memory"
Case E_POINTER
    fnOLEError = " Invalid Pointer"
Case E_UNEXPECTED
    fnOLEError = " Unknown Error"
Case S_OK
    fnOLEError = " Success!"
End Select

End Function
```

Lastly, below is a screenshot of where the code bugs out for me on some occasions.

[image]

Comment: Bumping this thread up!

Comment: Having posted a late answer to your API issue embedding a sheet range into userform, I'd like to know if it resolved your problem. If so feel free to accept my answer by ticking the green checkmark and/or upvote if you want to honour my research; anyway I'd appreciate your feedback :-) @Flohabenicht

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to prefix API declarations under `VBA7` *(versions since 2010+)* by `PtrSafe`, you have to take care of all changed argument types and function results to `LongPtr` (only for pointers to a → handle or → memory location), as well. Note that you have to provide for these also within your own procedure declarations.

**Overview** about needed changes in your API declarations (marked by **`!!`**, otherwise: *`OK`*)

---

- 1. *OK* Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" Alias "IsClipboardFormatAvailable" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
- 2. **!!** Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" Alias "OpenClipboard" (ByVal hwnd As **LongPtr**) As Long
- 3. *OK* Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" Alias "CloseClipboard" () As Long
- 4. **!!** Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByRef PicDesc As uPicDesc, ByRef RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As **LongPtr**, ByRef IPic As IPictureDisp) As Long
- 5. **!!** Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As **LongPtr**, ByVal lpszFile As String) As **LongPtr**
- 6. **!!** Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" Alias "CopyImage" (ByVal handle As **LongPtr**, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As **LongPtr**

Comment: I was dealing with a slightly different version of this code. I had to make a few extra changes in addition to changing some of the `Long`s to `LongPtr`s to get this to work on the latest Excel on Windows 10. I changed both the `PastePicture` and `CreatePicture` functions to return an `Object` instead of `IPicture`. In addition, I had to change the `IPic` variable's type within `CreatePicture`  to `Object` instead of `IPicture`.